# Does the Playstation 4 Camera work on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, ps4, playstation-move

My PS Eye (PS3) just fell off the TV and smacked the ground hard, now its not working.
Where I live the PS Eye is a lot more expensive than the PS4 version, could I just grab the PS4 Camera for use on PS4 AND PS3?

Comment: Nope;  same way you can't use Kintect from XB1 on the 360

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Amazon reviews](https://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx3FWWG0I6AGJVN/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B00BGAA3S2) (literally the only source I could find for this), *no*, you cannot use a PS4 camera for the PS3.

The capabilities of the two devices are very different, and it sounds like the plugs are different and incompatible with PS3.